Token with two pair adresses
Hi I do have 21M of a token B$anta adress token : J1RKSUrtorgPn7oKntYVMDAuiKu46kccSsddB7UkSV6o but when I tape it in Dexscreener I obtain two pair adresses what does it main please ?
Thanks
